# Read a non .NET DLL version from C#?

Tags: c#, dll

I have a folder with some DLLs in it (not .NET  assemblies) and I would like to read the file information in them. Things like the version, name... etc. What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use the FileVersionInfo object. Here's an example from the Microsoft website that gets the version info from notepad.exe

```
public void GetFileVersion() {
    // Get the file version for the notepad.
    FileVersionInfo myFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("%systemroot%\\Notepad.exe");

    // Print the file name and version number.
    textBox1.Text = "File: " + myFileVersionInfo.FileDescription + '\n' +
       "Version number: " + myFileVersionInfo.FileVersion;
 }
```

Stolen from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.getversioninfo.aspx).

Comment: I like this. Works for both .NET and non-.NET, and doesn't require loading the dll and reflection like other more popular methods for .NET dlls.