# C# getting version of unmanaged dll

Tags: c#, unmanagedresources

I'm calling an unmanaged dll from my managed c# code and wanted to check I'm calling the right version.

The code I'm trying to load the assembly (to then get the resource file and then get the version) is:
    cur_version = Assembly.LoadFile("X:\Workspace\yreceipts_pos\yRprintProcessor\Debug\yRprintProcessor.dll");
It's failing because of this error:
`The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131018)`

Does anyone know how to get around this or have a better way to check the version of an unmanaged dll from managed c# code?

Thanks in advance, 
Richard

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349943/read-a-non-net-dll-version-from-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated by logicnp; the Assembly.Load is for managed assemblies only. To determine the version of any version-ed file you can use System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(filename) and to load and call unmanaged procedures in DLLs you can refer to these articles:

http://blogs.msdn.com/jonathanswift/archive/2006/10/02/780637.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/jonathanswift/archive/2006/10/03/Dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-.NET-_2800_C_23002900_.aspx

Good luck...

Answer (score 4):

The reason it fails is becuase you cannot use Assembly.Load to load unmanaged dlls. See the link suggested by David Brown.